# Determine how many distinct pairs

Tags: combinatorics

> Given a set of distinct elements $\{x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6,x_7,x_8 \}$
>   how many distinct (order doesn't matter) pairs $(y,z)$ is it possible to obtain?

I just got stuck here. I believe it is $\binom{8}{2}$ but in the  book it says $36$.

Comment: just as a side note: this is the difference between combin and combina in excel. You did combin (combination) and the result should be used with combina (where repetition allows) 28+8=36

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. The number $\binom{8}{2}$ enumerates the pairs $(y,z)$ where $y<z$, but the pairs can also be of the form $(y,z)$ with $y=z$: 
$$(x_1,x_1),(x_2,x_2),\dots,(x_8,x_8).$$